# How can I access a field outside the entity from a twig file that is the template of another attribute in Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

In my `createQuery` I am adding an `addSelect` with a count of a relation and I want to access that count from a twig file that is the template of another attribute.

The object "object" in the twig is the representation of the entity, but it does not include the virtual field that I created using the `addSelect` of the query.

I tried everything, in fact accessing the `datagrid` but with that he would be duplicating the queries.